# How to get a combobox's selected item from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox, selecteditem

Okay, so I have form1 and form2. Form1 has a combobox that form2 needs to access. On form2 I created a new class that inherits form1. Like so.

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
   public form2()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      //from here I create tasks that reference the code in the newClass class
   }
}

public class newClass : projectname.form1
{
   public newClass()
   {
      //methods I access from from the above code
   }
}
```

I don't get any cross-threading issuses, but for some reason every time I try to get any type of value from that combobox, it's always null or an empty string. I've tried:

```
If (combobox.selecteditem == @"C:\")
{
    //do something
}
```

And:

```
If (combobox.text == @"C:\")
{
    //do something
}
```

And:

```
If (combobox.selectedindex == combobox.items.indexof(@"C:\")
{
    //do something
}
```

And:

```
If (combobox.selecteditem == combobox.findstringexact(@"C:\")
{
    //do something
}
```

Normally, I would just use: (in my case it's -1 for some reason)

```
If (combobox.selectedindex == -1)
{
    //do something
}
```

This works just fine, however the items in the combobox won't always be the same so you see why this isn't an accurate method. I've been reading countless posts and it seems like

```
combobox.selecteditem
```

is my best choice considering I'm using the DropDownList type of combobox. Nothing happens when I use this except that It gives me a warning to put (string) on the left side of the '=' sign. Like so:

```
If (combobox.selecteditem == @"C:\")
{
    //gives warning that I need (string) on left side of '='
}
```

If I do this, no warnings, but still nothing.

```
If ((string)combobox.selecteditem == @"C:\")
{
    //do something
}
```

The combobox is being populated with this on form1_load:

```
        string[] combobox = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string box5 in combobox)
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(box5);
        }
```

I'm using C#, Windows Form Application, .Net Framework 4.0

If anyone could shed any light on this, It would be much appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out on this one. :)

Comment: `public class form1 : form1.form2` - What? Form1 doesn't have to be related to form2, it just need a reference to form2 so it can access the combobox.

Comment: What does `public class form1 : form1.form2` mean? How can `form1` inherit from `form1.form2`? And what do you mean by "On form2 I created a new class that inherits form1." How can you create a class "on a form"? Is the code you are showing part of `form1` or `form2`? And on what form is `combobox` located? I'm sorry, but I totally don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry. I actually screwed up the first part. I'll edit my question to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

I have verified that the following code will work:

```
        if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == @"C:\")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"C:\");
        }
```

My guess is that you are referencing the wrong combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand why you need to *inherit* here something in order to be able to access internal control value.

Should be enough, instead, just do something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form 
{
    ComboBox _combo = new ComboBox(); 

    public string ComboSelectedItem
    {
       get 
       {
          if(combo == null || combo.SelectedItem == null) 
              return null;

          return combo.SelectedItem as string;
       }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form 
{   

    Form1 _form1Object = null;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
       _form1Object = form1;
    }


    public void DoSomethingUsingComboItemValueFromForm1()
    {
        .....
        string comboSelectedValueOnForm1 = _form1Object.ComboSelectedItem;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you return the `SelectedItem` in a property named `SelectedValue`?